# How to resolve the error in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying a simple spring boot application with Intellij IDEA. I am stuck with so many error and quite unclear what is happening.

I have opened the Spring Initializer in the browser and tried to import the file into my IDEA. I have now have error and not sure how to proceed with that.

Any lead would be helpful.

here is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is my error

[image: sNAPSHOT OF ERRORS]

Comment: Can you please check JDK is set on project ?

Comment: Did you import it as a maven project or how? Which Intellij version are you using?

Comment: It seems that you are opening generated project not as a maven project, so IDEA can't find pom and import all libs. And also, it seems that your pom file is not correct: **dependency** of **spring-boot-starter-web** should be placed into **dependencies** section.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using Community version 2018.2.6

Comment: @RaheelaAslam yes it is already set

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov Yeah i encountered that error and deleted it.

Comment: @Mikz ok then run mvn clean install command.

Comment: Could you show a screen of the project tree in IDEA? Pom.xml and External libraries will be enough.

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov To add , I tried to download a mvn stand alone in my local disk and worked perfectly. I am surprised, why my plugins in IDEA dint work.

Comment: Maybe, corrupt jars downloaded by maven

`mvn clean install -U`

Don't forget to reimport dependencies in your IDE.
In IDEA you need to right click on pom file and choose Maven -> Reimport

Comment: Did you actually import it as a maven project or just opened it as a java project?

Comment: @M.Deinum I opened as an Java project

Comment: Import it as a maven project...